# Setting param to an element through jquery to ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to set param inside the ng-click i.e.,

I am able to set the id for the element, but I need to set the param inside the ng-click like `ng-click="editorder(5)"`

Here is the html

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x order-edit"  aria-hidden="true" ng-click='editOrder()'></i>
```

Script :

```
$(".order-edit").attr("id",message.data.id)
```

Help pls

Comment: why are you not trying this in the angualar way ?

Comment: Because i am doing works in jquery that's why, i will do it in angular for sure now,, but may i know how to do that in jquery ?

Comment: Can you post the html where you want to read the data attribute from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the id to a `$scope`

`$scope.id = message.data.id`

And use it as:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x order-edit" aria-hidden="true" id="editOrder" ng-click='editOrder(id)'></i>
```

**UPDATE:**

Assigned a DOM Id to the `li` element in above and fetched the element as:

`var editOrder = document.getElementById("editOrder");`

Now, binding the `ng-click` with the id.

```
editOrder.bind('ng-click', { id: message.data.id}, function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    alert(data.id);
});
```

PS: The update works for the javascript `click` event, its not tested for `ng-click`.

**EDIT:**

Tested for 'ng-click', it doesnt work.

You could look into this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/h49nz/) and create a custom directive that suits the requirement.

Comment: Is that possible to do it in jquery itself ??

Comment: @SulthanA, not possible without a directive.